# Remove records in Arango DB UI with length condition

Tags: arangodb

I want to delete some records from ArangoDB UI through the length condition.

For example : For a collection, I want to delete records that are having the length of a string object as 9

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your queston is quite vague, perhaps you could elaborate. What have you tried to do yourself to solve the problem? Do you have any sample code you wrote that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR item IN collection
  FILTER LENGTH(item.string) > 5
REMOVE item IN collection
```